# emberjs: making many to many associations

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In a large form for editing a user profile, I want to make some many to many associations with a different data type that doesn't have it's own route. I want to both have text based auto complete, and allow the creation of new instances of the minor data type. Both of those are easy once I have the controller created and associated with that section of the template:

How would I go about creating a SomeOtherTypecontroller and getting it instantiated, and added into the application even though there's no route associated with it? As the user enters text I can use that to query the api, so I don't need to populate this at creation time.

How would I render a section of the user profile template using that controller as the context, so actions properly map to the controller and data is sourced from it?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are trying to do can be easily achieved with the `needs` API.

For example:

```
App.ExampleController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['another'],
  anotherController: (function() {
    return this.controllerFor('another');
  }).property(),
  someObserver: (function() {
    return this.get('anotherController.someValue');
  }).observes('anotherController.someValue')
});
```

Instead of using `.property()` or `.observer()` for bindings you can do also something like:

```
 App.ExampleController = Ember.Controller.extend({
   needs: ['another'],
   anotherControllerBinding: 'controllers.another'
 });
```

Note that in the example the `AnotherController` does not need to correspond to any route.
For more info on the `needs` API take a look [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is correct as far as I can tell - there's a bug in ember-data right now where loading a hasMany relationship this way won't trigger a change event though, so I ended up needing to load the items on the side and bind them to the controller